# Win Rate based on $ Amount in Report

Tags: reporting

I want to show the Win Rate based on the Dollar amount inside a Report.

Dollar Win Rate: Total Amount from Opportunities Won / Total Amount from Opportunities Closed

How can I do this using a Report Formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Corrected formula:

```
EXP_AMOUNT:SUM / AMOUNT:SUM
```

This works only if the report is filtered to show only closed opportunities.

Comment: The ExpectedRevenue field doesn't exist. Is it OOTB or Custom?

Comment: It's OOTB. If you're on PE, you need to add it to the layout, or if you're on EE/UE/etc, you may need to check FLS (Setup/Opportunities/Fields/Expected Revenue/Set Field Level Security). It is derived from Amount * Probability.

Comment: @omgitsdev I just realized I had the formula wrong (I was mobile at the time). I've updated the answer to reflect how it should be built.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post that explains how to measure opportunity win rates in salesforce. It includes an accompanying video that demonstrates the steps. 
[Measure Win Rates in Salesforce](http://garysmithpartnership.com/opportunity-win-rates/)

Comment: Gary can you add the relevant information here? Personal promotion is generally frowned upon, but the real problem is that links can (and do) break over time, which means this answer could potentially becomes useless as it is.